# Truncate strings without break words

Tags: javascript, php, portability

I've been trying for the past hours to port a PHP code I had when I used to be active with the language to JavaScript in order to truncate strings interpolating them with dots (or any other string) with only partial success.

These are three already working algorithms developed about four years ago — two I did myself, the last, more complex, [I had a big help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27551290/753531)

```
function truncateBefore( $string, $length, $replacement ) {
    return substr( $string, 0, strrpos( substr( $string, 0, $length ), ' ' ) ) . $replacement;
}

function truncateAfter( $string, $length, $replacement ) {
    return substr( $string, 0, ( strpos( substr( $string, $length ),' ' ) + $length ) ) . $replacement;
}

function truncateMiddle( $string, $length, $replacement ) {

    $len = (int) ( ( $length - strlen( $replacement ) ) / 2 );

    // Separate the output from wordwrap() into an array of lines

    $segments = explode( "\n", wordwrap( $string, $len ) ) ;

    $end = end( $segments );

    if( strlen( $end ) <= ( $length / 2 ) && count( $segments ) > 2 ) {

        $prev = explode( ' ', prev( $segments ) );

        while( strlen( $end ) <= ( $length / 2 ) ) {
            $end = sprintf( '%s %s', array_pop( $prev ), $end );
        }
    }

    return new Strings(
        [ 'value' => reset( $segments ) . $replacement . trim( $end ) ]
    );
}
```

Used with this sample string:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum labore ad in consequat laboris in mollit
fugiat et do laborum aliqua laborum mollit amet laborum
duis irure irure ut aute pariatur pariatur duis dolore
in sed nisi occaecat officia nisi et esse ut magna et.';
```

They return, respectively:

```
Lorem ipsum labore ad in... // Before the "consequat"
Lorem ipsum labore ad in consequat... // After the "consequat"
Lorem ipsum...esse ut magna et. // Without breaking words, first 30 and last 30
```

Now that I explained everything, regarding my current problem (JavaScript), these were my attempts:

```
function truncateBefore( str, length, delimiter ) {
    return str.substring( 0, str.lastIndexOf( ' ', length ) ) + delimiter;
}

function truncateAfter( str, length, delimiter ) {
    return str.substring( 0, ( str.indexOf( ' ', str.substring( length ) ) + length ) ) + delimiter;
}

function truncateMiddle( str, $length, delimiter ) {
    // Nothing :(
}
```

The first two worked like a charm (as much as I could test, of course). The time spent reading the MDN paid off, but the third I couldn't even start because it relies on a few things JS doesn't have.

Sure, I could find "polyfills" and, in fact, I actually found (e.g. for [wordwrap()](https://j11y.io/javascript/wordwrap-for-javascript/)) but, in the end, the `end()`, `reset()` and `prev()` got the better of me.

Tried to resort to the PHP.JS project only to see it's now called Locutus, much bigger and somewhat complex without the plug-and-play...ability (ugh!) it used to have in the old days when I first met it.

How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like that:

```js
function truncateMiddle(str, length, delim) {

    // Replacing line breaks with spaces and splitting the string on spaces
    const words = str.replace("\n", " ").split(" ");

    // Final string variable
    let finalString = "";

    // Utility variables for the loops
    let letterCount = 0;
    let wordIndex = 0;

    // Adding `length` characters without splitting words.
    while (letterCount <= length) {
        finalString += `${words[wordIndex]} `;
        letterCount += words[wordIndex].length;
        ++wordIndex;
    }

    // Removing last space
    finalString.substr(0, finalString.length - 1);

    // Adding the delimiter
    finalString += delim;

    // Resetting utility variables
    letterCount = 0;
    wordIndex = words.length - 1;

    // Array storing the end words (will be reversed afterwards)
    const wordsEnd = [];

    // Adding `length` characters from the end, without splitting words
    while (letterCount <= length) {
        wordsEnd.push(words[wordIndex]);
        letterCount += words[wordIndex].length;
        --wordIndex;
    }

    // Adding the reversed array of words

    for (const word of wordsEnd.reverse()) {
        finalString += `${word} `;
    }

    return finalString;
}

console.log(truncateMiddle(
    "Lorem ipsum labore ad in consequat laboris in mollit\n" +
    "fugiat et do laborum aliqua laborum mollit amet laborum\n" +
    "duis irure irure ut aute pariatur pariatur duis dolore\n" +
    "in sed nisi occaecat officia nisi et esse ut magna et.",
    30,
    " ... "
));
```

It could probably use some optimization, but it does the job pretty well.

Comment: What about the other two? Did I port them correctly? Because I had some differences (word breakings) with shorter strings that doesn't happen with the original code

Answer (score 0):

You could use `truncateBefore()` or `truncateAfter()` functions to implement `truncateMiddle()`. To get the last N characters of the string I split words into and array (whitespace character is the separator), reverse it and then join words again (using whitespace character as a glue); I apply the same process to the return string.

**truncateMiddle() function clarification:** If (length parameter) > (str.length / 2) then some words will be repeated (the same words will be appear in the first N characters and the last N characters).

```js
function truncateBefore(str, length, delimiter) {
  return str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(' ', length)) + delimiter;
}

function truncateAfter(str, length, delimiter) {
    return str.substring(0, (str.indexOf(' ', str.substring(length)) + length)) + delimiter;
}

/**
 * Return first and last N characters of a string without
 * break any word.
*/
function truncateMiddle(str, length, delimiter) {  
  return truncateAfter(str, length, '') 
          + delimiter 
          + truncateAfter(str.split(' ').reverse().join(' '), length, '').split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
}

let res1 = truncateBefore("Lorem ipsum labore ad in consequat laboris in mollit fugiat et do laborum aliqua laborum mollit amet laborum duis irure irure ut aute pariatur pariatur duis dolore in sed nisi occaecat officia nisi et esse ut magna et.", 30, " ... ");

let res2 = truncateAfter("Lorem ipsum labore ad in consequat laboris in mollit fugiat et do laborum aliqua laborum mollit amet laborum duis irure irure ut aute pariatur pariatur duis dolore in sed nisi occaecat officia nisi et esse ut magna et.", 30, " ... ");

let res3 = truncateMiddle("Lorem ipsum labore ad in consequat laboris in mollit fugiat et do laborum aliqua laborum mollit amet laborum duis irure irure ut aute pariatur pariatur duis dolore in sed nisi occaecat officia nisi et esse ut magna et.", 30, " ... ");

console.log("truncateBefore: " + res1);
console.log("truncateAfter: " + res2);
console.log("truncateMiddle: " + res3);
```

If you want avoid repeated words, you can divided the string finding the first whitespace character beginning from the middle of the string.

```js
function truncateAfter( str, length, delimiter ) {
    return str.substring( 0, ( str.indexOf( ' ', str.substring( length ) ) + length ) ) + delimiter;
}

/**
 * Return first and last N character of a string without
 * break any word.
*/
function truncateMiddle(str, length, delimiter) {
  let middle = str.indexOf(' ', str.length / 2);
 
  return truncateAfter(str.substring(0, middle), length, '') 
          + delimiter 
          + truncateAfter(str.substring(middle).split(' ').reverse().join(' '), length, '').split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
}


let res = truncateMiddle("This is a test.", 110, " ... ");

console.log("truncateMiddle: " + res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this source for truncate by words:
[Yii2 core StringHelper:truncateWords](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/f7f3934226340b3095f770d93056ebd6fb3ad504/framework/helpers/BaseStringHelper.php#L140)

Comment: Yii2 is PHP Framework. The question is about porting the original, working, PHP code to Javascript ;-)

Comment: @BrunoAugusto First change your PHP code, your written PHP code for truncate string by word is not interesting.

Comment: 1) It's a 4-year-old code (or more) 2) It's not interesting for **you** but it served its purpose back then 3) This is a fragment of a whole thing I've extracted to comply with Stack Overflow's guidelines of having an example complete and verifiable and blah, blah, blah. In the real deal where this code has been extracted from I have a full prototypization of Strings as an Object, similar to what we have in JS